# Finding a principal element in an ideal in a cubic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I am struggling with how to find a principal element for each of $(2, 1 + \sqrt[3]{5})$ and $(2, \sqrt[3]{25} - \sqrt[3]{5} + 1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{5}]$. Working with norms here seems ugly. The main aim is to prove it is a PID via factoring $(2)$, $(3)$, $(5)$, $(7)$ and the Minkowski bound.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Well one way would be to use [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) to find $(\sqrt[3]{25}+2\sqrt[3]{5}+3)$ for the first ideal and $(\sqrt[3]{25}-\sqrt[3]{5}+1)$ for the second.

Comment: Could you also give me for $(3, 1 + \sqrt[3]{5})$ (which comes from $(3)$), I have sorted out the others. Thanks!

Comment: That would be generated by $(2-\sqrt[3]{5})$.